# Sphinx search returns false in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent, sphinx

I have installed Sphinx Search in laravel using composer and have generated the config file for it

**Config**

```
return array (
    'host'    => '127.0.0.1',
    'port'    => 9312,
    'indexes' => array (
        'my_book_index' => array ( 'table' => 'books', 'column' => 'book_id', 'modelname' => 'Books'  ),
    )
);
```

and when i tried to query from my controller i get the result as false

Query in controller

```
$results = SphinxSearch::search('t','my_book_index')->get();

dd($results);
```

Result

```
bool(false)
```

Do it require any additional configuration or why the result is always empty

Answer (score 0):

You have to put search tearm > min_word_len. You can find min_word_len in sphinx server configuration file sphinx.conf. Just try using few more characters.

OR

Set the match mode to Extended.

```
SphinxSearch::search('t','my_book_index')
              ->setMatchMode(\Sphinx\SphinxClient::SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED)
              ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have SphinxSearch running on your server before anything.
[Scalia's sphinxsearch package](https://github.com/scalia/sphinxsearch) is only used to access Sphinx inside Laravel.

I suggest you to check that page that explains [how to set up Sphinx.](http://atlchris.com/1996/working-with-sphinx-search-engine-on-a-lamp-linux-apache-mysql-and-php-stack-server/)